# How can i render the {columns.render} from array in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, arraylist, react-hooks

**Hello Everyone!**

I would like to know how can i render {columns.render} in React.js (typescript)

Do you have any ideas for this please?

```
const columns = [
        { title: '#', key: 'key', 
        render: (key) => <a>{key}</a>
        },
        { title: 'Order Number', key: 'orderNumber', 
            render: (item) => <Link href={`/orders/[orderId]`} as={`/orders/${item.id}`}>
                <a>{item.orderNumber}</a>
            </Link>
        },
        { title: 'Order Name', key: 'orderName' },
        { title: 'Date', key: 'date',
            render: (item) => moment.utc(item).local().format('DD MMM - hh:mm A')
        }
    ]
```

Comment: `columns[index].render(props)` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like that, in the return function of your component:

```
const yourThingToRender = ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3", "elem4"]
  return (
    <>
      {
        columns.map((item, index) => item.render && item.render(yourThingToRender[index]))
      }
    </>
  );
};
```

In yourTHingToRender, you need to put the object required to be rendered. I just put random strings for the example.

Comment: Yes, right. i got it. Thanks in advance both of you!

Comment: There is maybe an easyer way to test if render is undefined, if someone knows about it ?

Comment: In my case i just write like this. column.render?column.render(props):'';  @TheTisiboth